# Linq to XML create elements with unique parent

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Having this Linq statement to create an XML

```
new XElement(ns + "SpecialRegisters",
  from reg in registers
  where reg.IsUpdateRegister
  select new XElement(ns + "UpdateRegisters",
    new XElement(ns + "RegID",
        new XAttribute("ID", registers.IndexOf(reg).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'))
    )
  )
)
```

Is it possible to create a unique UpdateRegisters element with multiple RegID.
If there are no update registers there should not exist any UpdateRegisters element.

Comment: How about this : new XElement(ns + "SpecialRegisters",
              registers.Where(x => x.IsUpdateRegister).Select((x,i) => new XElement(ns + "UpdateRegisters", 
                  new XElement(ns + "RegID", new  XAttribute("ID", i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'))))));

Comment: creates more than 1 UpdateRegisters

Comment: The use : ns + "UpdateRegisters" + i.ToString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this instead:

```
var result=new XElement(ns + "SpecialRegisters");
var updateRegister=register.Where(e=>e.IsUpdateRegister);// To not repeat the same query twice
if(updateRegister.Count()>0)
{
 result.Add( new XElement(ns + "UpdateRegisters", 
                          updateRegister.Select((e,i)=> new XElement(ns + "RegID",i));
}
```

### Update

If you want to do it all in the same statement then you could do this:

```
 var updateRegister=register.Where(e=>e.IsUpdateRegister);// To not repeat the same query twice
 var result=new XElement(ns + "SpecialRegisters", updateRegister.Any()?
                         new XElement(ns + "UpdateRegisters", updateRegister.Select((e,i)=> new XElement(ns + "RegID",i)):null );
```

### My solution based on yours (miguelmpn)

Speed is not important, as I'm saving a simple and small file..

```
new XElement(ns + "SpecialRegisters", Registers.Registers.Singleton.Any(x => x.IsUpdateRegister) ?
                     new XElement(ns + "UpdateRegisters", Registers.Registers.Singleton.Where(e => e.IsUpdateRegister).Select((e, i)=> new XElement(ns + "RegID", i))) : null)
```

Comment: That's one solution, but my intention is to keep the code cleaner by having it all on the same linq query. (if possible of course)

Comment: IMHO doing this is enough cleaner and readable. Sometimes is better is split your operations in more than one line. Anyway here is another solution doing all in the same statement

Comment: In the update query you are selecting all the registers, I need to select only the ones that have IsUpdateRegister set to true

Comment: Now it works... the first step with updateRegister its not necessary because the Select() will only create the ones that are needed and Registers.Registers.Singleton.Any(x => x.IsUpdateRegister) will create only one UpdateRegisters if needed

Answer (score 1):

I think the one of [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload fits for this task very well.

```
var specialRegisters = 
new XElement(ns + "SpecialRegisters", 
             Registers.Registers.Singleton.Where(reg => reg.IsUpdateRegister)
                                          .Select((reg, i) => new XElement(ns + "RegID", i))
                                          .Aggregate(new XElement(ns + "UpdateRegisters"), 
                                                     (upReg, reg) => 
                                                     {
                                                         upReg.Add(reg);
                                                         return upReg;
                                                     }, 
                                                     upReg => upReg.HasElements ? upReg : null));
```

This approach will enumerate collection only once.
Third parameter of `Aggregate` method is key value of this approach, which return `null` in case no elements was added.

My own opinion to comment: *but my intention is to keep the code cleaner by having it all on the same linq query*.

I think keeping this kind of logic in one statement is not clean approach. I think one of idea of cleanliness is that reader of your code will understand your intentions faster.

You can extract creating `UpdateRegisters` element to the dedicated method

```
private XElement CreateUpdateRegistersOrNullIfEmpty(XNamespace ns,
                                                    IEnumerable<YourType> data)
{
    return data.Where(reg => reg.IsUpdateRegister)                
               .Select((reg, i) => new XElement(ns + "RegID", i))
               .Aggregate(new XElement(ns + "UpdateRegisters"), 
                          (upReg, reg) => 
                          {
                              upReg.Add(reg);
                              return upReg;
                          }, 
                          upReg => upReg.HasElements ? upReg : null));
}
```

Then use it

```
var specialRegisters = 
    new XElement(ns + "SpecialRegisters", 
                 CreateUpdateRegistersOrNullIfEmpty(ns, Registers.Registers.Singleton));
```

Comment: Aggregate works well too, thank you :)
I'm also using a method to save the SpecialRegisters, I just was trying to avoid to use IF statements. I think both awnsers provide a simpler code.